# ng-model is not updating in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

Acutally I am learning angularjs. I've introduced a problem is that when I click ng-click, ng-model is not updating. My code is as follows,

```html
<div ng-repeat="product in cart">
    <input type="number" ng-model="product.quantity" ng-required class="input-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="product.quantity++">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="product.quantity--">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-click` expects an expression, not generic JavaScript code.  your event log is surely showing `Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: product.quantity++` https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/ueoe?p0=product.quantity%2B%2B.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<button type="button" ng-click="product.quantity = product.quantity+1">+</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="product.quantity = product.quantity -1">-</button>
```

Comment: you're welcom. I was glad to help you:)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp">
<div  ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="product.quantity" ng-required class="input-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="product.quantity = (product.quantity +1)">+</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="product.quantity = (product.quantity -1)">-</button>
</div>
</div>
```